# Стиль с расширением .php

Tags: php, css

```
HTML:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="compress_css.php" type="text/css">

PHP:
compress_css.php
header('Content-type: text/css');
ob_start("compress");
function compress($buffer) {
/* Удаляем комментарии */
$buffer = preg_replace('!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!', '', $buffer);
/* Удаляем табуляции, пробелы, переводы строки и так далее */
$buffer = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t", ' ', ' ', ' '), '', $buffer);
return $buffer;
}
/* Список CSS файлов */
include('master.css');
include('typography.css');
include('grid.css');
include('print.css');
include('handheld.css');
ob_end_flush();
```

Что скажете по поводу моей затеи? Во всех ли браузерах будет работать? (Тестировал на своём тапочке, через браузер Опера - работает)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Во всех ли браузерах будет работать?

Вы выполняете обработку на сервере. Нет ни одной причины, почему для одного браузера она будет выполняться иначе, чем для другого.

> Что скажите по-поводу моей затее?

Что скаж**е**те по *(дефиса нет)* поводу моей зате**и**.

Скажу, что это велосипед, для минификации стоит использовать yui compressor и аналоги, для сборки стилей - либо сборщик типа gulp, либо, что еще лучше, препроцессор - LESS, Stylus, SASS. И что действительно необдуманная замена всех пробелов приведет к ошибкам в многословных правилах, не говоря уж о том, что и банальный `font-family: 'Courier New';` благополучно скончается.

Comment: Вопрос о рентабельности идеи, а не как будет работать предоставленный скрипт.

Comment: @TheDoctor нерентабельна, потому что на дебаг уйдет полгода, а потом на руках окажется еще один yui compressor.

Comment: @Etki, тут две ветки размышлений - отдача стилей через php и сжатие онных.  
Про первое ты ничего не написал, а зря - мне тоже интересно мнение.  
А вот со вторым полностью согласен.

Comment: @TheDoctor, ну в первом случае будет неполноценный клон sass. Я не вижу смысла раздавать разные стили для разных страниц, это идет вразрез с принятыми практиками кэширования, когда отдается ровно один файл ровно один раз.

Comment: @Etki, ну почему же нет смысла - одной строкой можно получить разные комбинации стилей, в зависимости от требования админа, например.  
Можно поделить огромный файл на кучу файликов поменьше, этакие модули. И т.д.  
Идей использования, если подумать и включить фантазию, выйдет много! :)

Comment: @TheDoctor я уже написал, почему раздавать меняющиеся стили - это антипаттерн.

По поводу кучи файлов - попробуйте препроцессор. Это разговор в ключе "зачем мне шаблонизатор, если php шаблонизатор".

Comment: @Etki, видимо сколько людей, столько и мнений...  
Благодарю за предложение.

Comment: Поддержу @Etki. Игра не сто́ит свеч. Использую LESS и на время разработки крупных проектов, я разделяю файлы со стилями для удобства, но все они потом компилируются в один единый файл css. Смысла от того, чтоб делать это "на лету", а тем более велосипедить, как правильно заметил @Etki, я не вижу.

Answer (score 2):

У меня тоже через PHP собирается конечные стили.
Хотя и на пару порядков сложнее, но мне кажется это очень удобным - подключаю кучу стилей одной строкой, управляю доступом, добавляю "за ширмой", etc...

Answer (score 1):

Затея хорошая, но как будет обработан такой стиль:
`border: 1px solid #999;`
или такой:
`margin: 5px auto 15px auto;`

Отвечаю: все поплывет.

Comment: Интересно почему?

Comment: @densmith, потому что после минификации кода с помощью вашей функции, получится следующее: `border:1pxsolid#999`, вместо `border: 1px solid #999`. Это некорректный `css`. Убедитесь сами: http://jsfiddle.net/q2oy1gpm/

Comment: Да ёперный театр, вопрос не в валидности регулярки, а в целесообразности идеи!

Comment: Я, кажется, ответил на вопрос о целесообразности: если инклюдить те или иные селекторы в зависимости от ситуации — то да, а вот минификация через регулярку — затея опасная, можно наплодить багов и пр.